# Seting text of a list view element crashes app, java nullpointer exception on measureHeightOfChildren

Tags: java, android

THIS IS THE ACTIVITY THAT IS SUPPOSE TO SHOW THE CONTACT INFORMATION. AS YOU CAN SEE, THIS ACTIVITY WILL SHOW CONTACTS BASIC INFO LIKE NAME, CELLPHONE, ETC. IT ALSO HAS TO SHOW THE LIST OF ADDRESSES OF THE RESPECTIVE CONTACT.

```
public class ViewContactActivity extends Activity 
{
private TextView name;
private TextView cellphone;
private TextView displayCellphone;
private TextView workphone;
private TextView displayWorkphone;
private TextView email;
private TextView displayEmail;

private ListView listView;

private Contact contact;
private ArrayList<Address> addressList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_contact);

    this.name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    this.cellphone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cellViewTextView);
    this.displayCellphone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cellDisplayTextView);
    this.workphone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.workViewTextView);
    this.displayWorkphone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.workDisplayTextView);
    this.email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailViewTextView);
    this.displayEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailDisplayTextView);

    this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addressListView);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    contact = (Contact) i.getSerializableExtra("Contact");

    this.name.setText(contact.getFirstName() + " " + contact.getLastName());
    this.displayCellphone.setText(contact.getCellPhone());
    this.displayWorkphone.setText(contact.getWorkPhone());
    this.displayEmail.setText(contact.getEmail());
}

protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    this.addressList = contact.getAddresses();
    populateList();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_contact, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }

    return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void populateList() {
    ArrayAdapter<Address> adapter = new AddressListAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

 private class AddressListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Address> {
        public AddressListAdapter() {
            super (ViewContactActivity.this, R.layout.address_listview_item, addressList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null)
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.address_listview_item, parent, false);

            Address address = addressList.get(position);


            TextView addressName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressNameTextView);
            addressName.setText(address.getAddressName());
            TextView addressStreet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.streetDisplayTextView);
            addressStreet.setText(address.getAddressStreet());
            TextView addressNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberDisplayTextView);
            addressNumber.setText(address.getAddressNumber());
            TextView addressCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityDisplayTextView);
            addressCity.setText(address.getAddressCity());
            TextView addressState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stateDisplayTextView);
            addressState.setText(address.getAddressState());
            TextView addressZip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zipDisplayTextView);
            addressZip.setText(address.getAddressZip());

            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

THIS IS THE MAIN ACTIVITY. IT MAKES AN INTENT TO START ViewContactActivity WHEN THE USER CLICKS ON A CONTACT.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private ListView listView;
ShowFieldsNewContactActivity activity  = new ShowFieldsNewContactActivity();
public static ContactsManager cManager = new ContactsManager();
private Object[] Contacts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactListView);
}

protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Contacts = cManager.getContactListObj();

    this.listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewContactActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Contact", (Contact) Contacts[arg2]);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    populateList();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.add_contact:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowFieldsNewContactActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void populateList() {
    ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter = new ContactListAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

 private class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
        public ContactListAdapter() {
            super (MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_item,  Contacts);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null)
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

            Contact currentContact = (Contact) Contacts[position];

            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            name.setText(currentContact.getFirstName() + " " + currentContact.getLastName());
            TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
            phone.setText(currentContact.getCellPhone());
            TextView email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
            email.setText(currentContact.getEmail());

            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

CONTACT ACTIVITY

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact>, Serializable
{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String cellPhone;
private String workPhone;
private String email;

private ArrayList<Address> addresses;

public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String cellPhone, String workPhone, String email)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
    this.workPhone = workPhone;
    this.email = email;
    this.addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();

}

public String getFirstName() 
{
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) 
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() 
{
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) 
{
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getCellPhone() 
{
    return cellPhone;
}

public void setCellPhone(String cellPhone) 
{
    this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
}

public String getWorkPhone() 
{
    return workPhone;
}

public void setWorkPhone(String workPhone) 
{
    this.workPhone = workPhone;
}

public String getEmail() 
{
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) 
{
    this.email = email;
}

public void addAddress(Address address1)
{
    this.addresses.add(address1);
}

public ArrayList<Address> getAddresses()
{
    return this.addresses;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Contact another) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

}
```

ADD ADDRESS ACTIVITY

```
public class AddAdressActivity extends Activity
{
private TextView addressName;
private TextView addressStreet;
private TextView addressNumber;
private TextView addressCity;
private TextView addressState;
private TextView addressZip;

private EditText addressNameEditText;
private EditText addressStreetEditText;
private EditText addressNumberEditText;
private EditText addressCityEditText;
private EditText addressStateEditText;
private EditText addressZipEditText;

public static Contact contact;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_adress);

    this.addressName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adressNameTextView);
    this.addressStreet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.streetTextView);
    this.addressNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberTextView);
    this.addressCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityTextView);
    this.addressState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stateTextView);
    this.addressZip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zipTextView);

    this.addressNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adreesNameEditText);
    this.addressStreetEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.streetEditText);
    this.addressNumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberEditText);
    this.addressCityEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cityEditText);
    this.addressStateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.stateEditText);
    this.addressZipEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zipEditText);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    contact = (Contact) i.getSerializableExtra("Contact");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_adress, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;

        case R.id.save_contact:
            Address address = new Address(this.addressNameEditText.getText().toString(), this.addressStreetEditText.getText().toString(),
                    this.addressNumberEditText.getText().toString(), this.addressCity.getText().toString(), this.addressStateEditText
                    .getText().toString(), this.addressZipEditText.getText().toString());
            MainActivity.cManager.addContact(contact);
            contact.addAddress(address);
            finish();
            return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

THIS IS THE XML FILE FOR THE VIEW CONTACT ACTIVITY

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ViewContactActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cellViewTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="@string/cell_phone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/workViewTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cellViewTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cellViewTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/work_phone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emailViewTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workViewTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/workViewTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/email" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/workDisplayTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workViewTextView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cellDisplayTextView"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cellDisplayTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cellViewTextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cellViewTextView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="63dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emailDisplayTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/emailViewTextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/emailViewTextView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workDisplayTextView"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/addressListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailViewTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

THIS IS THE XML FOR HOW THE ADDRESS WILL LOOK AS A LIST VIEW ITEM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/addressNameTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/addressStreetTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addressNameTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addressNameTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/street_text_view" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/addressNumberTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addressStreetTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addressStreetTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="@string/addres_number_text_view" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/addressStateTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addressCityTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addressCityTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/state_text_view" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/addressZipTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addressStateTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addressStateTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/zip_code_text_view" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/addressCityTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addressNumberTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addressNumberTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/city_text_view" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stateDisplayTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addressStateTextView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cityDisplayTextView"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/zipDisplayTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addressZipTextView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stateDisplayTextView"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cityDisplayTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/addressStateTextView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/numberDisplayTextView"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/streetDisplayTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/addressNumberTextView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addressNameTextView"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberDisplayTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/addressCityTextView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/streetDisplayTextView"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AND FINALLY THIS IS WHAT IS GIVING ME THE LOGCAT

```
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930): Process: com.example.contactlist, PID: 1930
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at             edu.uprm.ece.icom4035.activities.ViewContactActivity$AddressListAdapter.getView(ViewContactA    ctivity.java:112)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at          android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at     android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327     )
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native       Method)
```

I HAVE TRIED TO FIX THE PROBLEM, BUT I DON'T KNOW MUCH ABOUT THE MEASURE HEIGHT MESSAGE THAT THE LOG CAT IS GIVING TO ME.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Show us 112 line of code in ViewContactActivity

Comment: Dear Lord, your capslock is on.

Comment: Read the log.  It tells you exactly what and exactly where - `NullPointerException
04-03 02:27:03.566: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at             edu.uprm.ece.icom4035.activities.ViewContactActivity$AddressListAdapter.getView(ViewContactActivity.java:112)`

Answer (score 1):

In your `getView` you have to use the inflated view to retrieve the row items. For every findViewById inside getView change from `findViewById` to `view.findViewById`. For instance

```
TextView addressName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressNameTextView);
addressName.setText(address.getAddressName());
```

to

```
TextView addressName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.addressNameTextView);
addressName.setText(address.getAddressName());
```

Answer (score 1):

in ViewContactActivity.AddressListAdapter.getView() you should use:

```
TextView addressName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.addressNameTextView);
```

instead of:

```
TextView addressName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressNameTextView);
```

Comment: Thank you, thanks for taking the time to answer my question :)